# Как изменить иконку у jar с чашкой кофе?

Tags: java

Добрый день, пытаюсь сменить у jar файла иконку. Для этого использую данную конструкцию

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

   public static void main(String[] args){

 Main.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("src/resources/imagesi/mylogo.png")));

 }
```

но почему то постоянно подчёркивает красным this. и пишет

> Cannot use this in a static context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если честно, первым делом хочется просто отправить в ближайший онлайн-переводчик. Машина вам напрямую выдала фразу "... static ...", из которой и так все ясно.

Ваш код внутри main выполняется вне какого-либо экземпляра класса - main является статичным методом. Поэтому this в этом контексте в принципе не существует, о чем вам и говорит машина.
Для решения проблемы достаточно обратиться к классу по имени, а не через `this.getClass()`

```
Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("src/resources/imagesi/mylogo.png")
```

Отдельно замечу, что ресурс, скорее всего, у вас будет доступен как `imagesi/mylogo.png` без префикса `src/resources`.

Comment: Main.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Main.getClassLoader().getResource("imagesi/mylogo.png"))); но при данной конструкции подчёркивает getClassLoader() и просить создать либо метод getClassLoader()  либо изменить getClass() а когда меняешь пишет Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setIconImage(Image) from the type

Comment: @VargSieg Ну вы поинтересуйтесь, какие методы есть у вашего класса и у какого класса определен метод getClassLoader(), Вот первое, что мне по этому слову гугл показал: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Comment: @m.vokhm честно сказать читал но не понял вашу мысль у моего класса только один метод main."у какого класса определен метод getClassLoader() в смысле ? Мне нужно создать отдельный клас в котором нужно определить метод getClassLoader() и вызвать его в методе main ?

Comment: Ваш метод наследует все методы, которые определены для класса `Object`. `getClassLoader()` в их число не входит - он определен у метода `Class`. См. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Comment: Вы пытаетесь вызвать `getClassLoader()` у своего класса - но такого метода нет. Надо сначала получить его класс (объект класса `Class`), а уж у него вызывать `getClassLoader()`. Вам же Etki ясно написал: `Main.class.getClassLoader()`, а вы пишете `Main.getClassLoader()`.

Comment: @m.vokhm справедливости ради, в ответе сначала `.class` был пропущен

Comment: Тогда я извиняюсь за свой излишне суровый голос :) Это, однако, не отменяет необходимости читать справку и знать, какие методы есть у наших классов и чьи методы нужно вызывать, чтобы решить свою задачу.

Answer (score 1):

*Полный пример готового решения №1:*

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main1 extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4465997357046781244L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Main1 instance = new Main1();
        /**
         * Относительный адрес файла изображения. Относительно местоположения
         * файла-класса.
         */
        final String imgPath = "imagesi\\mylogo.png";
        instance.setIconImage(
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Main1.class.getResource(imgPath)));

        instance.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

*Полный пример готового решения №2:*

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main2 extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7810262901547572556L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Main2 instance = new Main2();
        instance.setIconImage(
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(new File("resources/imagesi/mylogo.png").toString()));
        instance.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: А при работе второго метода всё работает иконка меняется на окне но когда создашь  jar его иконка не меняется и окно не открывается ?

Comment: @VargSieg "когда создашь jar его иконка не меняется и окно не открывается" -- см. внимательно ответ от Etki

Comment: Эти примеры показывают идеи решения. 
Метод№1. Можно написать перехватывания NullPointerException (если файла-иконки нет на месте).
Метод№2 Будет работать если корректно разместить данные в папке проекта.
Например: app.jar, resources/imagesi/mylogo.png
Запуск java -jar app.jar

Comment: @m.vokhm всё просмотрел, но ответа не понял подскажите на что обратить внимание ?

Comment: @VargSieg **"ресурс, скорее всего, у вас будет доступен как imagesi/mylogo.png без префикса src/resources."** Когда программа работает из-под IDE, ей доступны файлы по путям, известным системе. Когда она работает из jar, classloader'у эти пути (могут быть) недоступны. И нужно убедиться, что все нужные ресурсы пакуются в jar. Его можно открыть и посмотреть содержимое любым архиватором.

Comment: Если нужно чтобы иконка программы находилась внутри *.jar-файла, то использование метода

Comment: `Main1.class.getResource(imgPath)` 
наилучший вариант, т.к. позволяет, при желании перемещаться внутри файловой иерархии и искать нужный файл.
`java.net.URL url = Main1.class.getResource(imgPath);
  String filePath = url.getFile();
  File file = new File(filePath);
  File parentDir = file.getParentFile();
  //...`

Comment: @m.vokhm верно я с начало не обратил внимание, что папки resources в которой находиться иконка в jar нет значит она туда и не запаковывается, а почему ?

Comment: @varg-sieg Потому что при создании *.jar-архива структура папок и сам графический файл, где находились в проекте не перенеслись в jar-архив.

Comment: @AnatolyKosorukov не правильно спросил как сделать чтобы они перенеслись в архив ?

Comment: @varg-sieg Все способы можно разделить на три категории: \s\s 
1. командная строка (утилита [jar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/jar.html), [howto](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html));
2. средствами (мастерами, опциями) конкретной IDE;
3. сторонними утилитами ([7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), например).

Comment: @AnatolyKosorukov в чём может быть причина что он родными средствами туда не добавляет ?

Comment: @varg-sieg Это зависит от "родных средств".
 
Возможно, нужно внести коррективы в конфигурационные файлы экспорта в *.jar-файл.